# Grouped product show price without tax in product listing

Tags: magento-1.9

We're facing a Magento bug.
We want to display prices excl Tax and in category product listing for a grouped product it shows the price including VAT (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uQ5w.jpg ) and in product page ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h38M.jpg ) it shows the product excluding Prices.

We should have in product listing the same minimal price from the product page which is 58$ but it shows 49$ the price incl Tax.

This problem is only for grouped products, for simple products display the right price in category and in product page.

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.1
I've take a look in price.phtml file and found the code at line 452, I've tried to change the code but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?